# How to create filter with multiple AND conditions?

Tags: regex, google-sheets-formula

I have a working formula `=FILTER(B2:B; REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B2:B);  TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; Tabellenblatt2!E3:E5))=false)` - filtering conditions are placed in `Tabellenblatt2!E3:E5`.

Now i want to add additional filtering conditions, placed in `Tabellenblatt2!F3:F5` - and can't find correct syntax to combine both ranges from `Tabellenblatt2!E3:E5` and `Tabellenblatt2!F3:F5` with an `AND`.

Tried some variants like these - but no success:

`=FILTER(B2:B; REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B2:B);  AND(TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; Tabellenblatt2!E3:E5);TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; Tabellenblatt2!F3)))=false)`

`=FILTER(B2:B; REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B2:B);  (TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; Tabellenblatt2!E3:E5))+(TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; Tabellenblatt2!F3)))=false)`

**PS**: In reality both ranges with filtering conditions have some thousands of strings - that is why i need to place them into different ranges, to remain below limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following formula:

```
=FILTER(A2:A,NOT(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A2:A),TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,C2:C,E3:E,F3:F))))
```

[image]